# Failed to load ApplicationContext inside the @TestConfiguration class

Tags: java, spring, junit5, spring-test, spring-bean

I'm using `@TestConfiguration` annotation to define bean provider for the JUnit5 test class.

- A test class is annotated with:

  - `@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)`
  - `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`.

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyTest {

    ...

}
```

- A configuration class is annotated with

  - `@TestConfiguration`.

```
package com.example;
    
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    
@TestConfiguration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

        
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to inject local server port inside the configuration class with `@LocalServerPort` annotation, but get a `Failed to load ApplicationContext` error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.MyTestConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"`.

I was using `@LocalServerPort` successfully in the test class, but decided to move it along with other objects which use it to the `MyTestConfiguration` class to make test class more clear.

Comment: Have a look at this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14877#issuecomment-603873031

Comment: The `@Lazy` annotation did the trick. Thank you, @Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Lazy` annotation to the test configuration class. More info [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14877#issuecomment-603873031).

From the [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation):

> If this annotation is not present on a @Component or @Bean definition,
> eager initialization will occur. If present and set to true, the @Bean
> or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean
> or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory. If present and
> set to false, the bean will be instantiated on startup by bean
> factories that perform eager initialization of singletons.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).